# VBA error extracting data from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have been running the same code over several subs, but just one of them that is exactly the same has been giving me this error and I don't know why:
VBA - Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error'

This is the code and I made a comment where the error refers to:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim customerBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

' make weak assumption that active workbook is the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the customer workbook
filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
caption = "Please select an input file "
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
' copy data from customer to target workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(14)
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'the line below is where the error refers to
targetSheet.Range("A1", "CA50000").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A1", "CA50000").Value

' Close customer workbook
customerWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain it is that line? Are targetSheet and sourceSheet pointing to the correct sheets? Does targetWorkbook have at least 14 sheets? Is the target worksheet, or are the cells, protected? Are you able to set the values manually?

Comment: Thank you. The file was too big, and by deleting more cells it worked.